# How can I shield against micro-meteors?

Tags: debris, shielding

It is well known that micro meteorites, space junk, and other small objects can put a dent (Or rip through) in a spacecraft quite effectively. How can I protect people, sensitive electronics, and other items from impacts from these items?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Whipple shields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whipple_shield) are used for this very thing. The basic idea is that when the object strikes the first layer, it breaks apart, and the resulting pieces have a low enough energy to be stopped by the other layer(s). They have the added benefit of being much lighter than, say, a single thick slab of aluminum or titanium.

[This site](http://ares.jsc.nasa.gov/ares/hvit/basic.cfm) has some good photos of ground-tested Whipple shields and their variations.